# Can I separately bind the X and Y properties of Point at xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I want to separately bind the X and Y properties of Point, feasible?
If this point is an object's property, feasible?
Create a new class and add implicit conversion to Point, feasible?
(Chinese, bad English, translated by Google)

Like this?@Trifon

```
<!-- language: lang-c# -->

public class BindingPoint : Animatable
{
    public double X
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(XProperty); }
        set { SetValue(XProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty XProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(double), typeof(BindingPoint), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));
    public double Y
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(YProperty); }
        set { SetValue(YProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty YProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(double), typeof(BindingPoint), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));

    public BindingPoint() { }
    public BindingPoint(double x, double y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public static implicit operator Point(BindingPoint bp)
    {
        return new Point(bp.X, bp.Y);
    }
}
```

It works in c# code, like "**Point p = new BindingPoint(1,1);**".
But it doesn't works in xaml code!

```
<Path>
    <Path.Data>
        <LineGeometry>
            <LineGeometry.StartPoint>
                <!--Type must be "Point"-->
                <local:BindingPoint X="10" Y="10"/>
            </LineGeometry.StartPoint>
        </LineGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

@Clemens I want to binding Y to a changing value(*value*) for each EndPoint.
What should I do?

```
<Path StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="Cyan" Canvas.Left="300" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <Path.Resources>
        <sys:Double x:Key="value"/>
    </Path.Resources>
    <Path.Data>
        <GeometryGroup>
            <LineGeometry StartPoint="50,20">
                <LineGeometry.EndPoint>
                    <Point X="30" Y="{StaticResource value}"/>
                </LineGeometry.EndPoint>
            </LineGeometry>
            <LineGeometry StartPoint="50,20">
                <LineGeometry.EndPoint>
                    <Point X="50" Y="{StaticResource value}"/>
                </LineGeometry.EndPoint>
            </LineGeometry>
            <LineGeometry StartPoint="50,20">
                <LineGeometry.EndPoint>
                    <Point X="70" Y="{StaticResource value}"/>
                </LineGeometry.EndPoint>
            </LineGeometry>
        </GeometryGroup>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Comment: No. Not feasible. Point is not a dependency object. Point.X and Point.Y are not dependency properties.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Show the XAML where you need to bind a Point's X and Y.

Comment: `Y="{StaticResource value}"` is not a Binding. Please tell us precisely what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: @Clemens edit & delete finished

Comment: re @Clemens : is too late in China now, see you 10 hours later~ Thx a lot

Comment: Y isn't DependencyProperty, can't use Binding and DynamicResource. And I can't use my Point class in xaml. So... It's absolutely impossible?

Comment: Nothing is impossible. Except for understanding your question, when it doesn't include a good [mcve] that clearly shows what you're trying to do. My general sense is that in the code you've posted, you're still missing some important steps: first, your `BindingPoint` class needs to expose a `Point` property that you can actually use as a source for the binding. The WPF binding system won't use your `implicit` operator to convert; you need to do that explicitly with the extra property. Second, you need to set that property any time the individual `X` and `Y` properties are changed.

Comment: Note that unless you want `BindingPoint` to be a _target_ of a binding (so far you've only shown it used as a source), it doesn't really need to be a dependency object. You can just implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. If you do want it to be a target of a binding, you'll need to find a place in the visual tree to host the object or set the binding in code-behind; WPF won't be able to set the binding via XAML if the `BindingPoint` object isn't part of the visual tree (it'll complain that it "can't find the governing FrameworkElement").

Comment: @PeterDuniho Oh! Thx! I'm going to try it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an new class that encapsulates a Point. Declare as properties of the new class X and Y. Then you will able to bind those properties of the new class.

Comment: @Flithor like what?